# Client MID is now a PARENT MID, but Data Views do not recognize this

Tags: marketing-cloud, data, data-views, parent, sfmc-business-unit

We recently added a BU under an existing MID, so now the MID is the "parent" to the newly created BU's MID.  However, when we run a simple query and add ent. as a prefix the system does not recognize the data view.

Do we need to deploy email before the system acknowledges that this account now has a Parent/Child relationship, or was the addition of the child BU done incorrectly?

Comment: Ent is only used if the DE is In the shared folder

Comment: System views also require ent. when there is a parent/child relationship.

Comment: That will always be the enterprise account. There is not more than one ENT regardless of hierarchy